# How to create a "typedef to a function pointer" in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm converting code from C++ to C#. I have this line:

```
typedef bool (*proc)(int*, ...);
```

Can I do that in C#?

Comment: Take a look at delegates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**  Yes.

**Generally:**
*(untested... just an outline)*

```
{
    bool AFunction(ref int x, params object[] list)
    {
        /* Some Body */
    }

    public delegate bool Proc(ref int x, params object[] list);  // Declare the type of the "function pointer" (in C terms)

    public Proc my_proc;  // Actually make a reference to a function.

    my_proc = AFunction;         // Assign my_proc to reference your function.
    my_proc(ref index, a, b, c); // Actually call it.
}
```

Comment: `proc` is a *Type*. `proc = AFunction;` wouldn't compile. (I can see this *"untested... just an outline"*, but test it.)

Comment: Ah - The params keyword was the part I was unaware of. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

[Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) are not strictly equivalent, but used for similar purposes.

Sample:

```
public delegate void DoSth(string message);

void foo(string msg) {
   // ...
}


void bar() {
  DoSth delg = foo;
  delg("tttttt");
}
```

If you are trying to invoke code from native C++ libraries using P/Invoke, you will need to take a look at [GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zdx6dyyh(v=vs.100).aspx) and [GetFunctionPointerForDelegate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/at4fb09f(v=vs.100).aspx) pair of functions.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, however, an answer that starts with *"Read up on..."* is generally not a real answer.

Comment: You also probably meant to do `DoSth delg = foo;`.